# If WebGL isn't supported by my graphics card by default, why should I use it?

Tags: webgl

I am looking to make a web-based game.  I saw lots of cool libraries that used WebGL (three.js, pixi.js, and more). The problem is that when I run the examples, I get the message "Your video card does not support Web GL."

Now, I could update my video card driver, but I'm not going to do that.  Why not?  Because the users of my game would never do that.  Asking casual users (my target audience) to update their video card driver is a complete non-starter.

Is there a way to use WebGL without alienating a ton of users?

PS: In case you are wondering, my laptop is no slouch.  I bought it Christmas '13 and it runs games like Bioshock Infinite flawlessly.

Comment: I think a better way of asking this question is why doesn't your graphics card support WebGL? What card is it? What OS are you running? What version of drivers? Maybe we can find out why. It's sad that your GPU manufacture made buggy drivers that would exposed your machine issues if WebGL was enabled on it. The solution is to complain to the GPU manufacture and put pressure on them not to do that. There's plenty of web pages that are starting to require WebGL. The new Google Maps for one, if you want the best features requires WebGL. So, it's up to the GPU vendors to keep the drivers working.

Answer (score 4):

There are generally two reasons a video card driver may be blacklisted for WebGL by browsers:

1. because it has bugs that would allow malicious web content to exploit the driver/GPU to attack the system, or
2. because it has bugs or limitations that would result in severely incorrect rendering.

Because of the first, it's unlikely that, as a content author, there's anything you could do to enable WebGL, as that would constitute a vulnerability.

And this is why you can run BioShock but not WebGL: since the game is a regular application, by running it you've already trusted it with your system, so there's little benefit in preventing it from abusing the GPU/driver. Web pages, on the other hand, are not assumed to be trusted in this way. (If you ask me, it's a long-standing architectural mistake that regular applications have such free run, but that's a rant for another day.)

Comment: Thanks, I understand the security risks.  My question was more along the lines of "Is it worth building a WebGL app if so many people cannot use it?"  To me, it seems like a risky technology.

Comment: @SpaceRook Well, that's part considering your audience and part speculation about future adoption. I don't think this is the place to find an answer to that.